# Find and replace n number of words

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-server-2016

I have below structure where certain words need replacing

```
declare @Words table(Find varchar(50),Replace varchar(50))

Insert Into @Words
Values('aeroplane','airplane'),
      ('centre','center'),
      ('holiday','vacation')
```

Currently having to loop through this table and do replace for each row using [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Would someone suggest an efficient way to achieve this rather than looping through the @words table?

Comment: I have no problem with iterating the table and making all replacements.

Comment: Is there even another way to do this, efficient or not.

Comment: Probably with a CLR object and Regex, @GuidoG , but I've no idea what the implementation would look like, as my C# skills are terrible.

Comment: @Larnu I was thinking of an sql method, if that is even possible.

Comment: Seems a simple thing to do with cross apply. Efficient? Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

As a general query to help you to modify your data with one query, you can do that :

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (ID INT, MyColumn VARCHAR(256))

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
(1, 'toto'),
(2, 'toto aeroplane titi'),
(3, 'le centre des holidays');

WITH
WORDS AS
(SELECT *
 FROM   (VALUES ('aeroplane','airplane'),
                ('centre','center'),
                ('holiday','vacation')) AS T (FindWord, ReplaceWord)
),
RPLC AS
(
SELECT ID, MyColumn, FindWord, ReplaceWord, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FindWord)  AS N,
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY MyColumn) AS M
FROM   MyTable AS T
       JOIN WORDS ON T.MyColumn LIKE '%' + FindWord + '%'
),
MODIF AS
(
SELECT ID, MyColumn, REPLACE(MyColumn, FindWord, ReplaceWord) AS MyNewColumn, N,
       M
FROM   RPLC 
WHERE  N = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT R.ID, M.MyColumn, REPLACE(MyNewColumn, R.FindWord, R.ReplaceWord), R.N, R.M
FROM   MODIF  AS M
       JOIN RPLC AS R ON M.ID = R.ID AND M.N +1 = R.N
)
SELECT * 
FROM   MODIF 
WHERE  M = N;
```

Just replace the final SELECT by a joined UPDATE with the original table